# How to get device font for using it in all app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I opened a Java native Android app and a Flutter Android app on the same device , the font of the native like default phone font .. like in the next screen..[image]
This screens from same problem here
I tried the solve of this problem here but ..

- this make native widget not get the font of phone !
- it's old and not work with me

Answer (score 1):

Flutter provides a DefaultTextStyle widget, which sets the default TextStyle for all descendant text widgets that don't have an explicit TextStyle specified.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!,
  child: const Center(
    child: Text('This text uses the device\'s default font.'),
  ),
),
```

Hope, it can help you.

Comment: This won't return the font of the device .. it will return the font type of bodyMedium

Comment: Have you tried? It works on my phone. I tried changing my phone fontStryle and size and it also automatically changes (after changing settings).

you can change bodyMedium property as your choose.

Comment: I changed font type in my device to other type .. but the font in app till Roboto