# How to dynamically change the font size in the text field

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield, flutter-font

I am writing an application on Flutter. I want to dynamically change the font size in the text field (actually TextFormField) when the number of characters in it increases. What I want to achieve is that when a user enters a huge amount, I want to reduce the font size of the text field to accommodate the entire amount.

Comment: Check this answer, you can use device's default fontsize based on user device font. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791484/12965265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very useful library you might want to take a look at which is [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text). It has some good controls for the dynamic text size change based on length and other attributes.